# Check nginx active connection without HttpStubStatusModule

Tags: networking, nginx, linux-networking, netstat

We want to check the number of active connections without the module `HttpStubStatusModule` being installed.

What would be the equivalent Linux command?

As a base line, we test on a machine with `HttpStubStatusModule` installed first, e.g.

```
Active connections: 6146 <-- from HttpStubStatusModule

# netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l
1266

# netstat -an | grep :443 | wc -l
25082
```

It seems to me that none of the above netstat give me the correct figure.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you consider checking only for established connections? e.g. `$ sudo netstat -antp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep nginx`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try excluding TIME_WAIT or grepping ESTABLISHED only

```
netstat -an | grep :443 | grep -v TIME_WAIT | wc -l
```

or

```
netstat -an | grep :443 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

Comment: The two commands give very different results. The first reports 3380 connections but the second - just 9. Why is that so? We use WebSockets. Can this be the reason?

Comment: This is very brittle. What if there is other software running on the machine, e.g. other monitoring systems ingress/egress which connects to 443?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the nginx server block

```
   location /nginx_status {
        # Turn on stats
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow all;
   }
```

we can check the connections status using the below URL

```
http://site_url/nginx_status
or
http://ip_address/nginx_status
```

Comment: The question clearly states: WITHOUT HttpStubStatusModule